# Reading generated HTML file from link

Tags: java, html

So my problem is that I can't seem to figure out how get the generated HTML page from a link, using Java. Here is the code I'm using:

```
public class URLReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.whalesonggames.com/oldforums/printthread.php?t=7495&pp=20&page=1");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

What I wanted to be printed out is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en" id="vbulletin_html">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <base href="http://www.whalesonggames.com/oldforums/" /><!--[if IE]></base><![endif]-->
    <meta name="generator" content="vBulletin 4.2.2" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.php?styleid=3&amp;langid=1&amp;d=1381351020&amp;td=ltr&amp;sheet=bbcode.css,popupmenu.css,printthread.css,vbulletin.css,vbulletin-chrome.css" />




    <title> transfers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.php?styleid=3&amp;langid=1&amp;d=1381351020&amp;td=ltr&amp;sheet=additional.css" />

</head>
<body>

<div class="above_body">
<div id="header" class="floatcontainer">
<div><a name="top" href="forum.php" class="logo-image"><img src="images/misc/vbulletin4_logo.png" alt="The Infinite Black Forums - Powered by vBulletin" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="body_wrapper">
<div id="pagetitle">
    <h1><a href="showthread.php?7495-transfers">transfers</a></h1>
    <p class="description">Printable View</p>
</div>



<ul id="postlist">
    <li class="postbit blockbody" id="post_1">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="datetime">04-10-2014, 06:59 AM</div>
        <span class="username">CaNc3r</span>
    </div>


        <div class="title">transfers</div>

    <div class="content">
        <blockquote class="restore">just wondering if we get our garrisons transfered also now? thank you.</blockquote>
    </div>
</li><li class="postbit blockbody" id="post_2">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="datetime">04-10-2014, 08:03 AM</div>
        <span class="username">replicatorz</span>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
        <blockquote class="restore">More at login says you can claim your grey corp with transfer.<br />
<br />
I am wondering what will happen now that I sold both sald corps in blue after claiming them on grey.  I suppose for now I will leave them undeployed/empty.</blockquote>
    </div>
</li><li class="postbit blockbody" id="post_3">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="datetime">04-10-2014, 08:07 AM</div>
        <span class="username">scoutsniper</span>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
        <blockquote class="restore">I'd like some clarification as well. When grey server opened GNG sent a lead at to grey to hold our spot. Since then we have tformed our red server garrison a full level. Does the mean our garrison on grey is 11 or 12?</blockquote>
    </div>
</li><li class="postbit blockbody" id="post_4">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="datetime">04-10-2014, 08:09 AM</div>
        <span class="username">CaNc3r</span>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
        <blockquote class="restore">anyone having login issues after reset?</blockquote>
    </div>
</li><li class="postbit blockbody" id="post_5">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="datetime">04-10-2014, 08:25 AM</div>
        <span class="username">replicatorz</span>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
        <blockquote class="restore">Never mind.  I reread login screen.  Question answered.</blockquote>
    </div>
</li><li class="postbit blockbody" id="post_6">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="datetime">04-10-2014, 08:50 AM</div>
        <span class="username">Ozymandias</span>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
        <blockquote class="restore">If the original Feb 10th duplicate was PURGED (entirely deleted), or if it never exited (post Feb 10th), it was re-duplicated today.<br />
<br />
If it is being used on the new server, there was no re-duplication. It has always existed there.<br />
<br />
You can type :TRANSFER to see what corporation you would transfer into.</blockquote>
    </div>
</li><li class="postbit blockbody" id="post_7">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="datetime">04-10-2014, 09:10 AM</div>
        <span class="username">Kolpo</span>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
        <blockquote class="restore">What if I tried to transfer a corp after feb 10th and it's dissapeared is there a way for me to get that back?</blockquote>
    </div>
</li><li class="postbit blockbody" id="post_8">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="datetime">04-10-2014, 09:11 AM</div>
        <span class="username">Ozymandias</span>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
        <blockquote class="restore"><a href="http://www.whalesonggames.com/forums/showthread.php?7497-Red-Blue-Green-Corporations-copied-to-Grey" target="_blank">http://www.whalesonggames.com/forums...copied-to-Grey</a></blockquote>
    </div>
</li><li class="postbit blockbody" id="post_9">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="datetime">04-10-2014, 09:12 AM</div>
        <span class="username">Ozymandias</span>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
        <blockquote class="restore"><div class="bbcode_container">
    <div class="bbcode_description">Quote:</div>
    <div class="bbcode_quote printable">
        <hr />

            <div>
                Originally Posted by <strong>Kolpo</strong>
                <a href="showthread.php?p=122005#post122005" rel="nofollow"><img class="inlineimg" src="images/buttons/viewpost.gif" alt="View Post" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="message">What if I tried to transfer a corp after feb 10th and it's dissapeared is there a way for me to get that back?</div>

        <hr />
    </div>
</div>If it existed on the old servers still, it was duplicated today. Otherwise there's not much we can do.</blockquote>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>


</div>
<div class="below_body">
<div id="footer_time" class="footer_time">All times are GMT -7. The time now is <span class="time">07:20 PM</span>.</div>

<div id="footer_copyright" class="footer_copyright">
    <!-- Do not remove this copyright notice -->
    Powered by <a href="https://www.vbulletin.com" id="vbulletinlink">vBulletin&reg;</a> Version 4.2.2 <br />Copyright &copy; 2014 vBulletin Solutions, Inc. All rights reserved. 
    <!-- Do not remove this copyright notice -->    
</div>
<div id="footer_morecopyright" class="footer_morecopyright">
    <!-- Do not remove cronimage or your scheduled tasks will cease to function -->

    <!-- Do not remove cronimage or your scheduled tasks will cease to function -->

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

which is what Google Chrome spits out when I do View > Developer > View Source.
However, when the above Java code is run, I get this instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en" id="vbulletin_html">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
<meta id="e_vb_meta_bburl" name="vb_meta_bburl" content="http://www.whalesonggames.com/oldforums" />
<base href="http://www.whalesonggames.com/oldforums/" />
<meta name="generator" content="vBulletin 4.2.2" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


        <meta name="keywords" content="android,infinite black,mmo,whalesong" />
        <meta name="description" content="Whalesong Games - Support, Wiki & Forums" />





    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

    if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') // Load jQuery Local
    {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="clientscript/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"><\/script>');
        var remotejquery = false;
    }
    else    // Load Rest of jquery remotely (where possible)
    {
        var remotejquery = true;
    }
    var SESSIONURL = "s=0f57ff6a3b879742a4f67d0cfea40613&";
    var SECURITYTOKEN = "guest";
    var IMGDIR_MISC = "images/misc";
    var IMGDIR_BUTTON = "images/buttons";
    var IMGDIR_MOBILE = "images/mobile";
    var vb_disable_ajax = parseInt("0", 10);
    var SIMPLEVERSION = "422";
    var BBURL = "http://www.whalesonggames.com/oldforums";
    var LOGGEDIN = 0 > 0 ? true : false;
    var THIS_SCRIPT = "printthread";
    var RELPATH = "printthread.php?t=7495&amp;pp=20&amp;page=1";
    var USER_STYLEID = "1";
    var MOBILE_STYLEID = "2";
    var MOBILE_STYLEID_ADV = "2";
    var USER_DEFAULT_STYLE_TYPE = "standard";
// -->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.whalesonggames.com/oldforums/clientscript/vbulletin-mobile-init.js?v=422"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.whalesonggames.com/oldforums/clientscript/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.vb.js?v=422"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.whalesonggames.com/oldforums/clientscript/vbulletin-mobile.js?v=422"></script>





<link rel="stylesheet" href="clientscript/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css?v=422" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.php?styleid=2&amp;langid=1&amp;d=1381351020&amp;td=ltr&amp;sheet=bbcode.css,editor.css,popupmenu.css,reset-fonts.css,vbulletin.css,vbulletin-chrome.css,vbulletin-formcontrols.css," />



    <title>The Infinite Black Forums</title>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="page-home">

<div id="header">
    <div id="header-left">
        <a href="forum.php?s=0f57ff6a3b879742a4f67d0cfea40613" class="logo-image" rel="external"><img src="images/mobile/vbulletin-logo.png" alt="The Infinite Black Forums - Powered by vBulletin" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="header-right">


            <a href="mobile.php?s=0f57ff6a3b879742a4f67d0cfea40613&amp;do=login" class="headericon" rel="external"><img src="images/mobile/login.png" /></a>

        <a href="mobile.php?s=0f57ff6a3b879742a4f67d0cfea40613&amp;do=gridmenu" class="headericon"><img src="images/mobile/gridmenu.png" /></a>
        <a href="search.php?s=0f57ff6a3b879742a4f67d0cfea40613&amp;search_type=1&amp;contenttype=vBForum_Post" class="headericon" rel="external"><img src="images/mobile/search.png" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="http://www.whalesonggames.com/community/tib/leaderboards/" class="headericon"><img src="images/mobile/merch.png" /></a>
<a href="https://www.theinfiniteblack.com/blackdollars/" class="headericon"><img src="images/mobile/bd.png" /></a>
    </div>


</div>



<div id="pagetitle" class="pagetitle ui-bar-b">
    <h1 class="pagetitle">vBulletin Message</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">   
    <div class="ui-body ui-body-e">We are sorry, this content is not supported via the mobile style. <br /><a href="forum.php?s=0f57ff6a3b879742a4f67d0cfea40613" rel="external">Click Here to go to the Forum Homepage</a>.</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">

<ul id="footer_links">


        <li class="first"><a href="mobile.php?s=0f57ff6a3b879742a4f67d0cfea40613&amp;do=login">Log in</a></li>



    <li><a href="register.php?s=0f57ff6a3b879742a4f67d0cfea40613" rel="external">Register</a></li>


        <li><a href="forum.php?styleid=1" class="fullsitelink" rel="external">Full Site</a></li>


    <li class="last"><a href="#top" class="scrolltop" rel="external">Top</a></li>

</ul>

<div id="footer_copyright" class="shade footer_copyright">
    <!-- Do not remove this copyright notice -->
    Powered by <a href="https://www.vbulletin.com" id="vbulletinlink">vBulletin&reg;</a> Version 4.2.2 <br />Copyright &copy; 2014 vBulletin Solutions, Inc. All rights reserved. 
    <!-- Do not remove this copyright notice -->    
</div>
<div id="footer_morecopyright" class="shade footer_morecopyright">
    <!-- Do not remove cronimage or your scheduled tasks will cease to function -->
    <img src="http://www.whalesonggames.com/oldforums/cron.php?s=0f57ff6a3b879742a4f67d0cfea40613&amp;rand=1397183042" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
    <!-- Do not remove cronimage or your scheduled tasks will cease to function -->

</div>

</div>



</div><!-- data-role="page" -->


    <script type="text/javascript">
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36823542-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
          })();
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

which is not what I want. Now, bear in mind I know almost nothing about web languages and how they work, but I think I've figured out that the second snippet of HTML "generates" the first snippet of HTML when the browser is loading the page. If that's wrong, please correct me. Anyways, is there any way to instead retrieve the "final version" of the HTML before it's displayed to the user in a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like The site you are trying to open doesn't recognize default User Agent.

Try adding something like this before URL object construction:

```
System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0");
```

Comment: Wow, great! Worked fine. How exactly does this code work? I'd rather understand the issue than copy/paste and have something similar later.

Comment: Looks like the site you tried to open in your code serves different content depending on browser. By default User_agent is set to something like "Java/1.5.0_19" (your Java version), and the site doesn't recognize it. Setting it to a common browser solves this problem.